# css style is overruled bij chromes user agent style sheet

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, overriding

My problem is as subscribed in the title. The part of css that is currently being overruled is this:

```
.domain, .incident, .chzn-container-single .chzn-single {
font-family: sans-serif}

.domain {font-weight: bold}
```

In firefox is show correctly but sadly in chrome it doesn't. Really hope someone could help me find a way to override this.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWFtO.jpg

Comment: Works fine - http://fiddle.jshell.net/qku6s/1/ - The user agent only applies default styling for HTML tags. Not classes.

Comment: Add a screen shot of the chrome inspect tool debugger.

Comment: Just added the screenshot

Comment: option is a form element and you probably cannot override that style?

Answer (score 0):

Chrome does not allow to style the font-weight for the option element (cf. your debug screen shot)
Firefox does allow it.

http://fiddle.jshell.net/cN5A4/1/

```
option {font-weight: bold;}
```

If you want to have the same styling you would need to resort to JS. For example https://github.com/fnagel/jquery-ui which turns the select into a list with links which you could than style as bold links...